# Alt/Option key after C-c in Aquamacs

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard, aquamacs

I'm working with Aquamacs on a Macbook with a German keyboard.  I've set the "Meta & German" option to make the alt/option key work as <kbd>Alt</kbd> when needed, but as <kbd>Meta</kbd> otherwise. So far so good.  Now I want to invoke a function that is bound to <kbd>C-c [</kbd> (`reftex-citation`). Unfortunately, I have now clue about how to type this: On the German keyboard the square bracket is bound to <kbd>Alt-5</kbd>, but apparently after <kbd>C-c</kbd> the following alt/option is interpreted by Aquamacs as Meta (or something completely different), because when I type <kbd>C-c</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt-5</kbd> I get the message: `^C ⌥5 is undefined`. Is there a way I can get the square bracket after <kbd>C-c</kbd>?

(In this specific case, I've simply rebound `reftex-citation` to another key, so no big deal, but I've met the problem in several variations now, so thought I'd find out what I'm doing or understanding wrongly.)

Comment: What does this mean: "I've set the "Meta & German" option to make the alt/option key work as Alt when needed, but as Meta otherwise"? How is it decided "when needed"?

Comment: Personally, for Aquamacs I have set EN layout despite the fact that I have DE keyboard and use RU for work... :) I just switch layouts when needed.

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).